# skipping parts of a matched lexical element or token

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I would like to match a "{NUM}" and then have the lexer rule return "NUM". so, I tried

```
NUM : ('{' { skip(); })  'NUM'  ('}' { skip(); });
```

But, that seems to skip everything and return empty on a match. would it be possible to skip parts of a lexer match ?

antlr 3.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invoking `skip()` anywhere in your rule will remove the entire token from the lexer, not just certain characters.

What you could do is this:

```
NUM
 : '{NUM}' {setText("NUM");}
 ;
```

Or, if `NUM` is variable, do:

```
NUM
 : '{' 'A'..'Z'+ '}' {setText($text.substring(1, $text.length() - 1));}
 ;
```

which removes the first and last char from the token.

### EDIT

> *smartnut007 wrote:*
>
> *Is there an equivalent way to do this for Tokens ?*

If you mean how to change the text of tokens inside parser rules, try this:

```
parser_rule
 : LEXER_RULE {$LEXER_RULE.setText("new-text");}
 ;

LEXER_RULE 
 : 'old-text'
 ;
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there an equivalent way to do this for Tokens ?